# Filter data contained in the m3u playlist

Tags: kodi, m3u, iptv

In my .xml file I use on codes, I select a m3u list and download the channel list, but this list includes channels from different countries, for example, can you filter the list by displaying only the channels of a particular country?
For example, how can I see the list of channels [TN] only excluding channel display [AR]

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1,[TN]_ZAYTOUNA_HIDAYA
http://iptvload.info:8000/live/xxx/xxx/13.ts
#EXTINF:-1,[TN]_AL_INSEN_TV
http://iptvload.info:8000/live/xxx/xxx/41.ts
#EXTINF:-1,[AR]_MBC_1
http://iptvload.info:8000/live/xxx/xxx/110.ts
#EXTINF:-1,[AR]_MBC_1HD
http://iptvload.info:8000/live/xxx/xxx/512.ts
```

This is part of the xml file

```
<expres><![CDATA[#EXTINF:(.*),(.*)\s(http.*://(.*)/live.*ts)]]></expres>
<page><![CDATA[http://iptvload.info:8000/get.php?username=xxxpassword=xxx&type=m3u]]></page>
```

Answer (score 0):

- [Regex for [TN]](http://rubular.com/r/NpbIdyCGjx) :

  ```
  EXTINF.*.*,(.*?TN.*)\n(.*)
  ```
- [Regex for all links in your example](http://rubular.com/r/JO87Ljlrjf) :

  ```
  EXTINF.*.*,(.*?)\n(.*)
  ```
- [Regex for all streams with logo](http://rubular.com/r/ZHSTpujHUX) :

  ```
  #EXTINF.*.*name="(.*)".*tvg-logo=(.*),(.*).*\n.*?(?=http|m3u8|rtmp|rtsp|mms)(.*[\d|\w])
  ```

  Here you have to set parameters for the XML file.